# How To store json values in a set of arrays in android

Tags: android, json

i have a json file like so :

http://da.pantoto.org/api/files

i want to store these values in variables to be used later. The values should be stored in some String array variables like id[], uploadDate[], url[].

i can find examples using ListView and ArrayAdapter. but thats not what i really want. Anyone can help??

Comment: What u have done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only an example to show how you can get the values from JSON. You need to store these values as you need.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("your response");
JSONArray filedetails = jsonObject.getJSONArray("files");
    for(int i=0; i<filedetails.size();i++){
       String id = filedetails.get(i).getString("id");
       JSONArray tagsdetails= filedetails.get(i).getJSONArray("tags");
       for(int i=0; i<tagsdetails.size();i++){
            //fetch values in it
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it exactly that way, You have to iterate trough the array and get each object properties individually and then if you want you could create an array to store each object property.

```js
//From the example: http://da.pantoto.org/api/files
JSONArray files = null;

//Creating service handler class instance
ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
 
//Making a request to url and getting response
String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall("http://da.pantoto.org/api/files", ServiceHandler.GET);
 
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
 
// Getting JSON Array node
files = jsonObj.getJSONArray("files");

//YOUR NEW ARRAY
String[] ids = new String[20];
String[] urls = new String[20];
//etc

//looping through All files
for (int i = 0; i < files.length(); i++) {
 JSONObject c = files.getJSONObject(i);
  
 String id = c.getString("id");
 String url = c.getString("url");
 //etc
 
 
 //HERE IS WHAT YOU COULD DO OPTIONALLY IF YOU WANT HAVE IT ALL ON A SINGLE ARRAY WITHOUT OBJECTS:
 ids[i] = id;
 urls[i] = url;
 //etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple way to do this. see i also done this kind of string array and later use

```
                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(strDocketListResponse);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jObj.getJSONArray("GetManifestDocketListResult");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject detailsObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String strDktNo = detailsObject.getString("Docketno");
                        String strDocketDate = detailsObject.getString("DocketDate");
                        String strOrigin = detailsObject.getString("Origin");
                        String strDestination = detailsObject.getString("Destination");

                        String[] strDocketNoDkt = new String[]{strDktNo};
                        String[] strDocketDateDkt = new String[]{strDocketDate};
                        String[] strDocketOriginDkt = new String[]{strOrigin};
                        String[] strDocketDestnDkt = new String[]{strDestination};                            

                        for (int sanjay = 0; sanjay < strDocketNoDkt.length; sanjay++) {
                            ItemCheckList itemCheckList = new ItemCheckList();
                            itemCheckList.setDocket_NO(strDocketNoDkt[sanjay]);
                            itemCheckList.setDocket_Date(strDocketDateDkt[sanjay]);
                            itemCheckList.setDocket_Origin(strDocketOriginDkt[sanjay]);
                            itemCheckList.setDocket_Destination(strDocketDestnDkt[sanjay]);
                            checkLists.add(itemCheckList);
                        }
                        checkAdapter = new ItemCheckAdapter(ActivityManifestEntry.this, checkLists, check_all);
                        manifestListView.setAdapter(checkAdapter);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```